# Is the theta bound of an algorithm unique?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

For example, the tightest bound for Binary search is `θ(logn)`, but we can also say it has `O(n^2)` and `Ω(1)`.

However, I'm confused about if we can say something like `"Binary search has a θ(n) bound"` since `θ(n`) is between `O(n^2)` and `Ω(1)`?

Comment: I don't understand what the question really is. You want to know if O(n^2) and Ω(1) implies θ(n)? The answer is "no". This is similar to 1<=x<=10 does not imply that x=5.

Answer (score 0):

- The **worst-case** execution of binary search on an array of size *n* uses *Θ(log n)* operations.
- **Any** execution of binary search on an array of size *n* uses *O(log n)* operations.
- Some "lucky" executions of binary search on an array of size *n* use *O(1)* operations.

The sentence "The complexity of binary search has a *Θ(n)* bound" is so ambiguous and misleading that most people would call it false. In general, I advise you not to use the word "bound" in the same sentence as one of the notations *O( )*, *Θ( )*, *Ω( )*.

- It is true that *log n < n*.
- It is false that *log n = Θ(n)*.
- The statement *log n < Θ(n)* is technically true, but so misleading that you should never write it.
- It is true that *log n = O(n)*.

Answer (score 0):

The "because" is wrong. Θ(n) is indeed compatible with O(n²) and Ω(1), but so is Θ(log n).

In the case of the dichotomic search, you can establish both bounds O(log n) and Ω(log n), which is tight, and summarized by Θ(log n).

You may not choose complexities "randomly", you have to prove them.